# How to open a file in my src directory using just the filename in INTELLIJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I want to open the file

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3\examples\assigment_4\src\file.txt
```

using the following code:

```java
BufferedReader hangmanWordsFromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
```

But it throws the exeption

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: HangmanLexicon.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

When I copy `file.txt` to

```
IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3\jre\jre\bin
```

it works.

Printing `System.getProperty("user.dir")` yields `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3\jre\jre\bin`.

How can I change `user.dir` path so that I can use `file.txt` as file name to open the file located at `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3\examples\assigment_4\src\`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The file has to be in a place that the code can see it.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `user.dir` for where the file is.  That property will point to whichever directory Java was run from.

Comment: what I have: http://prntscr.com/6lxs2m   this is my code: BufferedReader addWordsFromFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("wordlist.txt")); but I catch exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: wordlist.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your [working directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-application.html):

Go to `Run > Edit configurations`, select your run configuration and select your working directory (the one, where your file.txt is in).

Comment: thank you for your reply! I go to    run > edit configuration > application > choose my class > Working directory               is right IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0.3\examples\assigment_4\src\ Where should I change the path?